Aws hosted page
I am using aws cognito and need single sing on login screen (provider), I am told to use "Hosted UI customization" screen build in user pool cognito
Is there away to create own Cognito custom login page instead AWS Hosted UI customization
The Hosted UI customization can only style it and I need more than styling
Is there a way to do it with aws Amplify? if yes how is there any documentation.
this one doesn't work as SSO
https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/angular/connected-components/authenticator/configuration

You can write a custom login componnent using a frameworl such as React and then use CSS to style it. You can hook that into Cognito as well.

Thank John, but I need to use it instead of cognito hosted page as SSO. Do you have a document how to use it instead of cognito hosted page. I need all application redirected to this custom page
